# Get room list in socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I was wrote this code for join room on socket.io.

```
socket.on("requestJoinRoom", function(data){
     var rooms = io.sockets.adapter.rooms;
     for(var key in rooms){
           if(key == ''){
             continue;
           }
           else{
               console.log("room id="+key);
           }
     }
});
```

There are not code 'socket.join(key);'.
But prompt is printed "room id=###########"

I think it's mean socket.io has at least one room.
but I don't make any room.

How can I understand that?

My socket.io version is 1.3.5.

Comment: Maybe a default one? (Just a gues, I don't know anything about `socket.io`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every socket.io connection is automatically put in a room of its own at startup.  You can then add it to other rooms if you want.

From the [socket.io documentation](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/):

> Each Socket in Socket.IO is identified by a random, unguessable,
>   unique identifier Socket#id. For your convenience, each socket
>   automatically joins a room identified by this id.

Comment: Then, If I want join other room, I will leave current room before join other room???          -> socket.leave(currentRoom); -> socket.join(otherRoom);